# help calculating $\sum_{k=0}^n k!{n \choose k} ^2= \text{?}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to find the number of relations on $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ s.t. for all $x,y,z\in R.xRz \wedge yRz\to x=y$. One idea I had was choosing $k$ elements from $n$ then choosing another $k$ elements from $n,$ there are $k!$ bijections between these two sets so we just have to sum over $k$ and here I got stuck, tried finding another approach but came up with nothing.

Comment: But why do you want bijections? It seems to me that you are considering injective functions where the domain is a subset of $[n].$ but, for example $\{(1,2),(1,3)\} is a good relation. Am I missing something?

Comment: yes, pretty much the same thing, that's what I originally did to find this sum expression. An injection from a subset of [n] is the same as a bijection from a subset of [n] to a subset of [n] since it is a bijection on its image.

Comment: @YotamMaoz Yes, my problem with your approach, as explained in the answer is that you do not have to consider just injective partial functions, but all of them. Notice that this is nothing more than the functional relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be such a relation. For each $z\in[n]$ there is at most one $x\in[n]$ such that $x\mathrel{R}z$. The relation $R$ therefore defines a function

$$f_R:[n]\to[n+1]:z\mapsto\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }R^{-1}[\{z\}]=\{x\}\\
n+1,&\text{if }R^{-1}[\{z\}=\varnothing\,.
\end{cases}$$

In other words, $f_R(z)$ is the unique $x\in[n]$ such that $x\mathrel{R}z$ if there is one and is $n+1$ if no such $x\in[n]$ exists.

Conversely, if $g$ is any function from $[n]$ to $[n+1]$, the relation

$$R_g=\{\langle f(k),k\rangle:k\in[n]\}\cap\big([n]\times[n]\big)$$

has the desired property, and $f_{R_g}=g$. Thus, the map $R\mapsto f_R$ is a bijection from the set of such relations to the set of functions from $[n]$ to $[n+1]$. There are $(n+1)^n$ functions from $[n]$ to $[n+1]$ and therefore $(n+1)^n$ such relations.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is missing relations as commented above, you are considering just injective partial functions. To complete your argument You can go as follows: You pick a set of $[n]$ for the domain(say of size $k$) of the relation and you choose a different set of the codomain (say one of size $\ell$). Then you partition the codomain(into $k$ non empty blocks) and assign each block to an element in the domain (so you permute the blocks in $k!$ ways).
 I get
$$\sum _{k,\ell}\binom{n}{\ell}\binom{n}{k}{\ell \brace k}k!=\sum _{\ell= 0}^n\binom{n}{\ell}\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}{\ell \brace k}k!=\sum _{\ell= 0}^n\binom{n}{\ell}n^{\ell}=(n+1)^n.$$
Which makes sense, your relation is the functional relation for the right coordinate and you are just adding a dummy image to see when is the element not in the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Every relationship from $[n]$ to $[n]$ is just a subset of $[n]\times [n]$, so consider the $n\times n$ grid, what you have calculated is placing $k$ non-threating rooks on the grid. Your answer is equal to the sum of coefficients of the "rook polynomial" and does not have a closed form.

However, what this problem is asking is to place $k$ rooks on the $n\times n$ grid while they threat each other only on one axis, for example just vertically.

To count the answer over all $k$s, for each column of the grid, one can pick the position of the corresponding rook with a number between $0$ to $n$, where $0$ is leaving the rook outside of the grid.

This leads to $(n+1)^n$ possible outcomes.

Comment: Thank you, edited.

Answer (score 0):

The following function is used in statistical thermodynamics.

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} ^2\,k!\,x^k= (-x)^n U\left(-n,1,-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ where appears the Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function.

So, your case corresponds to $f(1)$ and the values are reported as sequence $A002720$ in $OEIS$. Accoring to $OEIS$, $a_n= n!\, L_n(-1)$ where appear   Laguerre polynomials.