Asymptotics for a sum of binomials
I am considering the following sum
$$ S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n k! \binom{n}{k}^2. $$
I would like to know how this grows as $n$ tends to $\infty$, ideally with an asymptotic lower bound. I only got relatively complicated expressions when I tried this myself, which I have included below.

Mathematica gave me that this sum can be expressed in terms of the confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind $U$ as follows:
$$ S_n = (-1)^n U(-n, 1, -1). $$
According to the NIST library of functions as the first parameter shrinks to infinity we can express $U$ in terms of Bessel functions, leading to
$$ S_n = n! \sqrt{e} J_0(\sqrt{-4n-2}) + n! \sqrt{2e} (-1)^n |Y_0(\sqrt{-4n-2})| O(1/\sqrt{n}) $$
for $n \rightarrow \infty$. However, this is clearly still not a very interpretable function. Since the original expression is quite simple, I was expecting an easier solution. Does anyone have some insight?

Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3970389/42969

I am not sure, but maybe use asymptotics for the Bessel functions? I am sure you'll find some here. Also the n! all over the place might mean that Stirling's approximation could play a role.

Maple gives $hypergeom([-n, -n], [], 1)$,  so not an elementary function...

Thanks for the comments. For some context, I am looking for the number of partial injections ${1, \dots, n} \longrightarrow {1, \dots, n}$. @Kraken I tried using Stirling, but didn't get anywhere. I was hoping for a more aesthetically pleasing alternative to Bessel functions...

If a heuristic approach is acceptable, switching from summation to integration and using Laplace' method
$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n k! \binom{n}{k}^2\sim\frac{\sqrt\pi,n^{1/4}(n!)^2}{\Gamma^2(\sqrt n+1/2)\Gamma(n-\sqrt n+3/2)}\sim\frac{e^{2\sqrt n}n!}{\sqrt{4\pi e\sqrt n}}$$
Numeric check (WA) confirms the answer - https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B100%7D+%28k%21+%28%5Cbinom%7B100%7D%7Bk%7D%29%5E2%29 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=100%21+e%5E%7B2%5Csqrt%7B100%7D%7D%2F%282%5Csqrt%7B%5Csqrt%7B100%7D%5Cpi+e%7D%29

@Svyatoslav Could one use Euler-Maclaurin and then try to find an asymptotic for the error term for a finer result?

@Svyatoslav that looks much more like what I am looking for. Would you mind elaborating on your approach? Do you simply try integrating $k! \binom{n}{k}^2$ from $0$ to $n$?

@Kraken, this is what I usually do. Using the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula - to estimate next asymptotic terms, and compare them with the first one (the integral). If the function has a sharp maximum on the interval, these terms can be much smaller then the integral. Then, if we need the rigorous proof, we estimate the error term. The program is suitable to our case.

I can provide the sketch of what I did - without rigorous proof. If this is acceptable, I can post my approach (sure, not the most elegant one :)

By entry $\text{A}002720$ of the OEIS, $S_n$ can be written in terms of the Laguerre polynomials as follows:
$$
S_n  = n!L_n ( - 1).
$$
Then, by the known asymptotics for $L_n(-z)$ and Stirling's formula, we deduce
$$ 
S_n  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2{\rm e}} }}n^{n + 1/4} {\rm e}^{ - n + 2\sqrt n } \left( {1 + \frac{{31}}{{48}}\frac{1}{{\sqrt n }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right)
$$
as $n\to+\infty$. Because of the positive correction term, I suspect that the leading order asymptotics is always a lower bound.
A reasonable lower bound may be obtained as follows. We use another representation given in the OEIS and obtain
$$
S_n  = \frac{1}{{\rm e}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(n + k)!}}{{k!^2 }}}  \ge \frac{{n!}}{{\rm e}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{n^k }}{{k!^2 }}}  = \frac{{n!}}{{\rm e}}I_0 (2\sqrt n ),
$$
where $I_0$ is a modified Bessel function. Since
$$
I_0 (2\sqrt n ) \ge I_{1/2} (2\sqrt n ) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\frac{{\sinh (2\sqrt n )}}{{n^{1/4} }}
$$
and
$$
n! \ge \sqrt {2\pi } \,n^{n + 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - n}  
$$
(see $\S10.37$, $\S10.39$ and $\S5.6$ in the DLMF), we deduce
$$
S_n  \ge \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{{\rm e}}n^{n + 1/4} {\rm e}^{ - n} \sinh (2\sqrt n ) = \frac{1}{{{\rm e}\sqrt 2 }}n^{n + 1/4} {\rm e}^{ - n + 2\sqrt n } \left[ {2{\rm e}^{ - 2\sqrt n } \sinh (2\sqrt n )} \right].
$$
The quantity in the brackets is very close to $1$ for large $n$, whence this bound is off by a factor of about $\mathrm{e}^{-1/2}$. It seems to me that
$$\tag{1}
I_0 (x) \ge \frac{{{\rm e}^x }}{{\sqrt {2\pi x} }}
$$
for any $x\ge 1$, which would eliminate the quantity in the brackets.
Addendum. By the results of this paper,
$$
I_0 (x) = \frac{{{\rm e}^x }}{{\sqrt {2\pi x} }}\left( {1 - \frac{3}{{8x}} + {\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} (R_2^{(K)} (x{\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}} ,0))} \right)
$$
where
$$
\left| {{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} (R_2^{(K)} (x{\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}} ,0))} \right| \le \left| {R_2^{(K)} (x{\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}} ,0)} \right| \le \sqrt {3{\rm e}} \frac{9}{{128x^2 }}
$$
for any $x>0$. Since
$$
 - \frac{3}{{8x}} + {\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} (R_2^{(K)} (x{\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}} ,0)) \le  - \frac{3}{{8x}} + \sqrt {3{\rm e}} \frac{9}{{128x^2 }} \le 0
$$
for $x\ge 1$, $(1)$ holds for at least $x\ge 1$. Consequently,
$$
S_n  \ge \frac{1}{{{\rm e}\sqrt 2 }}n^{n + 1/4} {\rm e}^{ - n + 2\sqrt n } .
$$
for $n\ge 1$.

Nice solution! I also suspected that the next asymptotic term should be $\sim\frac1{\sqrt n}$ - due to a considerably big error at numeric checks, but you provided its closed form. Thank you!

After this question, using $m=\sqrt n$
$$S_n=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2 e}}\,\exp\Bigg(m^2 \log \left(\frac{m^2}{e}\right)+2m \Bigg) \,\Bigg(1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {a_k}{m^k}\Bigg) $$ where the first coefficients are
$$\left\{\frac{31}{48},\frac{553}{4608},-
   \frac{222853}{3317760},\frac{9164693}{637009920},\cdots\right\}$$ which provides bounds.
